# Iterate through all rows returned from an Scala Anorm query

Tags: scala, anorm

I have a small Anorm query which is returning all the rows in the Service Messages table in my database. I would eventually like to turn each of these rows into JSON.

However, currently all I am doing is iterating through the elements of the first row with the `.map` function. How could I iterate through all rows so I can manipulate all the rows and turn it into a JSON object.

```
  val result = DB.withConnection("my-db") { implicit connection =>
    val messagesRaw = SQL("""
         SELECT *
         FROM ServiceMessages
      """).apply;

    messagesRaw.map(row =>
      println(row[String]("title"))
    )
  }
```

Comment: You can have a look at the documentation about [streaming support](http://playframework.github.io/anorm/#streaming-results)

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you do IS iterating all the rows (not only the first one) taking contents of title column from each row.
In order to collect all titles you need the following trivial modification:

```
val titles = messagesRaw.map(row =>
  row[String]("title")
)
```

Converting them to json (array) is simple as well:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
...
Ok(Json.toJson(titles))
```